# can't store the best list of neurons properly

Tags: python, arrays, list, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a object recognition AI from scratch, and I have a bug where I can't store the best list of neurons in the list bestNeurons. The problem is that I always end up with the last set of neurons. Sorry for the convoluted code in advance.

```
for x in range(numberOfGenerations):
trainingSample = random.randint(0, len(images))  # choose a random image in the sample file
for y in range(numberOfNeurons):
    selectedImage = random.randint(0, 4)
    weights[y] = random.uniform(0.8, 1.2)
    neurons[y] = weights[y] * average[y]  # Create a random configuration.
    if float(arrayOfImages[selectedImage][y]) == 0.0 == float(neurons[y]) * float(arrayOfImages[selectedImage][y]):
        dataGapArray[y] = 1.0
    elif float(arrayOfImages[selectedImage][y]) > float(neurons[y]):
        dataGapArray[y] = float(neurons[y]) / float(arrayOfImages[selectedImage][y])
    elif float(arrayOfImages[selectedImage][y]) < float(neurons[y]):
        dataGapArray[y] = float(arrayOfImages[selectedImage][y]) / float(neurons[y])
print(dataGapArray)
total = (sum(dataGapArray) / numberOfNeurons)
if total > bestScore:  # This is the part where I set the bestScore ad the bestNeurons
    print("New Best Score!:", total)
    bestNeurons = neurons
    bestScore = total

print("Last neurons:", neurons)

print("Best neurons:", bestNeurons)
print("Best score:", bestScore)
```

The code will print out something like this:

```
Current data gap array: [0.3540970933075369, 1.0, 0.35556737111502196, 0.6583839908684838, ...
New Best Score!: 0.576298162866769
Current data gap array: [0.2493125438801029, 0.339285693476224, 0.45029005330390104, ...
...
Last neurons: [102.72969175931665, 21.145554408239597, 26.591052468204936, ...
Best neurons: [102.72969175931665, 21.145554408239597, 26.591052468204936, ...
```

As you can see, the last set of neurons didn't set a new high score and shouldn't be stored as the set of best neurons. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line might be the culprit

```
bestNeurons = neurons
```

along with

```
("Last neurons:", neurons)
```

It's line 17 when I paste it in my editor.

If the neurons are the last neurons and the bestNeurons = neurons then by the transitive law last neurons = bestNeurons.

Comment: yes, that would make sense, but how would I fix it?

Comment: However, the two variables should be set to be equal only if a new bestScore is set, not everytime

Comment: I renamed total to totalScore in case the name total was used by another library of some sort, but it did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: when you set a list to be equal to another list using

```
listA = listB
```

it somehow seems to bypass condition statements. Instead, after initializing the listA with

```
for x in range(howLongYouWantYourListTobe):
    listA.append(0.0)
```

I had to copy the listA to the listB (or in this case bestNeurons to neurons) by using:

```
        for a in range(len(listB)):
        listA[a] = listB[a]
```

the final code is the following:

```
 if totalScore > bestScore:
    print("New Best Score!:", totalScore)
    for a in range(len(neurons)):
        bestNeurons[a] = neurons[a]
    bestScore = totalScore
```